# Laravel - Why am i not the owner of the files i upload (file permissions & owners)?

Tags: php, image, laravel, laravel-5

i has a class that uploads images, then resizes them with the an image manipulation library(Intervention/Image)

problem is whenever i upload the image, and the resize function is called on the image, intervention/image doesn't have permissions to manipulate it. and when i check the image - it doesn't belong to me. i has no idea why it belongs to "daemon". i can chown to me with terminal but it defeats the puropse because i want it resized immediately it uploads.

[image]

i tried php `chown()` but i didn't expect it to work as using chown on the terminal required sudo privileges.
here's the class that handles uploads. is there anything i'm doing wrong?

```
<?php
namespace App\Controllers\Helpers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Image;
class Uploads  {
public $file;
public $image;
public $thumb;
public $isUploaded;

public function __construct($image){
    $this->file = $image;
}

public function handle(){
    $data = ""; 
    if(is_array($this->file)){
        foreach ($this->file as $file) {
            if($file->isValid()){
                $path = base_path().'//public/';
                $name = str_replace('|', '', $file->getClientOriginalName());
                $file->move($path,$name);
                $data.= '|'.$path.$name;
                $this->isUploaded = true;
                chmod($path.$name, 0755);chown($path.$name, 'seun');
            }
        }
    } elseif($this->file->isValid()) {
        $data = '//public'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $this->file->move(base_path().$data);
        $this->isUploaded = true;
        chmod(base_path().'//public/'.$file->getClientOriginalName(), 0755);chown(base_path().'//public/'.$file->getClientOriginalName(), 'seun');
    } else {
        $this->isUploaded = false;
    }
    return $data;
}

public function thumb(){
    if(is_array($this->file)){
        foreach ($this->file as $file) {
            $image = Image::make($file)->resize(200, 150);
            $image->save(base_path().'//public/thumb/'.$this->file->getClientOriginalName());
        }
    } else {
        $image = Image::make($this->file)->resize(200, 150);
        $image->save(base_path().'//public/thumb/'.$this->file->getClientOriginalName());
    }
}

public function status(){
    return $this->isUploaded;
}
}
```

Attempting `chown()` returns this error

[image]

Comment: Try to setup a common group that belongs apache and you and chown your uploads folder to that group

Comment: just did that,didn't work